# class_exists está executando o spl_autoloader_register

Tags: php, spl, spl-autoloader-register

Eu criei um script simples pra carregar automaticamente classes usando o `spl_autoload_register`, mas notei um comportamento estranho, quando eu uso `class_exists` o `spl_autoload_register` é executado, exemplo:

```
<?php
function autoLoadClass($name) {
    echo 'spl_autoload_register: ', $name, '<br>';
}

spl_autoload_register('autoLoadClass');

class_exists('Foo');
class_exists('Bar');
class_exists('Foo\\Bar');
```

Saída:

> spl_autoload_register: Foo
>   spl_autoload_register: Bar
>   spl_autoload_register: Foo\Bar

Isto está correto? Existe alguma maneira de fazer o `spl_autoload` não ser chamado quando usar `class_exists`?

Comment: +1 essa pergunta é útil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com o Manual do PHP, basta definir o segundo parâmetro dessa função para `FALSE`.

Veja:

```
class_exists('Foo', false);
```

Veja o esqueleto dessa função:

`bool class_exists ( string $class_name [, bool $autoload ] )`

Ou seja, se definir o segundo parâmetro como `FALSE`, essa função não executa o carregamento automático da classe. Por padrão ela vem definida como `TRUE`.

Comment: Falta de atenção minha kk. Verdade. ~9min pra aceitar a resposta

Comment: Dessa vez, no Manual, estava certo. Costuma haver essas informações em  inglês e não ter em português. A melhor opção é perguntar no SOPT mesmo :p