# Desativar require do composer com php

Tags: php, composer

Tenho um exemplo de *JSON*:

```
{
    "name": "xxxxxx",
    "description": "xxxxx",
    "type": "beta",
    "license": "MITS",
    "authors": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Leonardo Vilarinho",
            "email": "leonardoi@outlook.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": 
    {
        "php": ">=5.5.12",
        "twig/twig" : "*",
        "respect/validation" : "*"
    },
    "require-dev" : 
    {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "*"
    },
    "config": 
    {
        "vendor-dir": "libs"
    }
}
```

Provavelmente eu terei mais `libs` no meu projeto, quero saber se há como eu desativar e ativar essas `libs` pelo PHP? Se sim, como posso fazer isso? (vou leigo quando o assunto é `composer`, por isso não conseguir nem tentar nada, as pesquisas não me levaram a nada).

Para apesar de elas estarem baixadas no projeto não serem carregadas no `autoload` do `composer`.

Comment: Eu não entendi bem, mas acho que o que seja é remover tempoariamente, remova as que não deseja, algo como: `"require": 
    {
        "php": ">=5.5.12",
        "twig/twig" : "*"
    }` e use o comando `php composer.phar update` (ou se for `composer update`), quando quiser ativar novamente basta readicionar e `"require": 
    {
        "php": ">=5.5.12",
        "twig/twig" : "*",
        "respect/validation" : "*"
    }` e use o comando `php composer.phar update`

Comment: Vou dar uma atualizada na pergunta, o objetivo é fazer na linguagem PHP mesmo, exemplo, tenho 3 dependências, mas não uso uma, então tem como cancelar ela no autoload do composer pela linguagem do php? Sem ficar retirando e adicionando ela via composer

Comment: Entendi, mas elas não carregam se não usa-las, vou adicionar uma resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O composer-autoloader usa o `spl_autoload_register`, as classes que estão no `"require":` só são carregadas se usar `new`, ou chamadas estáticas `Exemplo::teste();` executam os includes, ele funciona assim:

Se fizer isso a classe `Foo\Bar\Baz` **não** é carregada:

```
<?php
use Foo\Bar\Baz;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Se fizer isso a classe `Foo\Bar\Baz` é carregada, no momento que usa `new`:

```
<?php
use Foo\Bar\Baz;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Essa linha dispara o spl_autoload e inclui o ./src/Foo/Bar/Baz.php
$baz = new Baz;
```

Ou:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Essa linha dispara o spl_autoload e inclui o ./src/Foo/Bar/Baz.php
$baz = new Foo\Bar\Baz;
```

Se fizer isso a classe `Foo\Bar\Baz` é carregada no momento que chama o método `exemplo`:

```
<?php
use Foo\Bar\Baz;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Essa linha dispara o spl_autoload e inclui o ./src/Foo/Bar/Baz.php
Baz::exemplo();
```

Estender classes também dispara o autoload, mesmo que você não use a classe filha:

```
<?php
use Foo\Bar\Baz;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Essa linha dispara o spl_autoload e inclui o ./src/Foo/Bar/Baz.php
class Exemplo extends Baz {
}
```

### Como funciona o `spl_autoload_register`

- Ele só é executado se a classe ainda não existir
- Se usar o `use` não dispara e nem inclui nada, o `use` serve mais pra criar o `aliases` (apelidos)

Recomendo que leia:

- [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88023/3635)
- [class_exists está executando o spl_autoloader_register](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92858/3635)
- [PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80060/3635)